# Updating UITableView when returning from edit form, refresh entire table datasource or the row that was edited?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a UITableView filled with data from a JSON datasource in my `viewDidLoad()`.  I'm storing this JSON data in a dictionary at the top of my view controller code:

```
class InventoryListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var inventoryListTableView: UITableView!
    let textCellIdentifier = "textCell";
    var warehouseItems: [Inventory] = [];  //array for my items

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        inventoryListTableView.dataSource = self;
        inventoryListTableView.delegate = self;

        loadTableViewWithJSON();  //this loads my data into the warehouseItems dictionary created above

    }
...
}
```

Here's my `loadTableViewWithJSON()`

```
func loadTableViewWithJSON() {
        let urlString = "http://url.php";
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!;

        session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let responseData = data {
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>;

                    //                        print(json);

                    if let inventoryDictionary = json["inventory"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                        //                        print(inventoryDictionary);

                        for anItem in inventoryDictionary {

                            //                            print(anItem["quantityOnHand"] as? Int);  //works

                            if let id = anItem["id"] as? Int, let item = anItem["item"] as? String, let description = anItem["description"] as? String, let quantityOnHand = anItem["quantityOnHand"] as? Int, let supplierId = anItem["supplier_id"] as? Int, let supplierName = anItem["supplierName"] as? String {

                                let item = Inventory(id: id, item: item, description: description, quantityOnHand: quantityOnHand, supplierId: supplierId, supplierName: supplierName);
                                //                                print(item);

                                self.warehouseItems.append(item);
                            }
                        }
                        //                        print(self.warehouseItems[0].description); //works
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.inventoryListTableView.reloadData();
                        })
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Could not serialize");
                }
            }

            }.resume()
        }
```

Tapping one of the items segues into another view for editing the item that was tapped.  When the fields are changed and the item edited there is a big green check that calls a rest API and updates the data in my database (that my UITableView gets from).  Now when I click the Back button in my NavigationController it returns to the previous screen with my UITableView, but the values aren't updated.  I've tried running `tableView.reloadData()` in my `viewWillAppear()` but nothing works.  I've also tried calling my function that grabs the data from JSON but of course that just adds the updated data to the end of my tableView and I have an old copy of the data, and a fresh underneath.

My question is, should I just clear my UITableView and run my function that grabs the data once more?  Or should I just update the single row with the new data?  I thought updating the single row would be better for less overhead on my restful API.  Or would it be better to detect when I'm coming back from my editing view controller and reload all the data?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        // loadTableViewWithJSON(); // this duplicates the data in the tableview
        inventoryListTableView.reloadData();
    }
```

And my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
        let row = indexPath.row;
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(warehouseItems[row].item) -->  \(warehouseItems[row].quantityOnHand) on hand"

        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = warehouseItems[row].description;

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the body of `loadTableViewWithJSON()` (add to original question)

Comment: Edited and done.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `loadTableViewWithJSON()`, you're calling `self.warehouseItems.append(item)` which simply appends to the existing array.  This is why you're seeing duplicate data in your tableView.

Add `warehouseItems = []` to the top of you `session.dataTaskWithURL(url)` response block.  This will clear out the array so you can rebuild it from scratch with the updated data.

```
func loadTableViewWithJSON() {
    let urlString = "http://url.php";
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!;

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let responseData = data {
            warehouseItems = []
```

Once you make those changes, the following should work for you.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadTableViewWithJSON()
    inventoryListTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Final note, semicolons are not needed in Swift, we're free!

Comment: lol I know about the semicolons.  I find them comforting for some reason :)

Comment: If they bring you joy, then I can't argue. Was my suggestion able to resolve your issue?

Comment: I believe so! I'm working on it this morning.  It makes sense so much sense I dont' know why I didn't think of it in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: It's working as expected, except the first time the `UITableView` loads up when running the app, it's showing duplicates.  If I select something, edit it, and go back to the `UITableView` it shows the correct and updated values.  Only the initial loading of the table has dupes now.  I know it's because my `viewDidLoad()` and my `viewWillAppear()` are firing the function to populate the table.  I'm not sure why it's ignoring the `warehouseItems = []` the first time though.

Comment: This is probably due to the asynchronous nature of the network requests.  I have updated my answer to take this into account.